# Is there a museum pass or something for Naoshima in Kagawa Prefecture?

Tags: japan

From my reading I've discovered that there are several museums on Naoshima, where I'm going tomorrow. Each one seems to cost roughly $10-$20 individually. Personally, I'm disinclined to pay over and over to visit six small museums in one day.

Is there any sort of all-in-one pass? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to the [Benesse Art Site](http://www.benesse-artsite.jp/en/)?

Comment: Yes, the Benesse House, Art House Project, Chichu Art Museum, and so on. I've discovered the answer is 'no'-- you have to pay for them all separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Each attraction is separate. It's worth reading up on what each museum has to offer to be sure you're interested.

The Arthouse Project is grouped together, though-- you can see all of the houses for a single ¬$10 purchase.